# reference id with mongodb by laravel jenssegers

Tags: laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

i have two models, i need to get model A data that have reference in model B by array id, this is my model A object

```
 { 
    "_id": "62eb2f788345c04a74057903",
   "location": "usa"
 }
```

and this is my model B

```
 {
     "_id": "62eb2f788345c04a74057903",
     "name": "task",
     "desc": "test task",
     "location_id ":["62eb2f788345c04a74057903", "62eb2f788345c04a74057904"]
 }
```

how can i get model data A from model data B query by jenssegers library?
is there any other solutions for this case?
i've try use hasMany and belongToMany but the result is null,

Answer (score 0):

solve this using raw query mongo, [how to use lookup with jenssegers]
[1]: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/841#issuecomment-260106920

this is mongo db doc about lookup [how to use lookup with mongo]
[2]: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-unwind-example